# Convert group to sub-layer

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers

Is there a way to quickly convert a *Group* to a *Sub-layer* in Illustrator?

Comment: Make sublayer/layer drag the colored square into the newly created layer and ungroup. No need for a new file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select highlight all items in group and from the layers palette menu choose **collect in new layer**. This will eliminate the group (since it has no descendants) and make a new sublayer.

[image: Collect]

**Image 1**: Collect in new layer

Since this is easily recordable so you can bind it into an action that does this for you. So you could easily make a hotkey for this.

It is also possible to make a script that does this. No need to make a new file.

Comment: You don't even need to select all items in the group, you can just select the group itself and click "Collect in New Layer" and it'll directly convert the group to a layer (as of Adobe Illustrator CC in 2018).

Answer (score 2):

Just Ungroup the grouped object and it will automatically convert all objects in Sub-layers